# ROS Answers SE migration: mail glitch

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the top of the screen, there is an image of an envelope that turns red when there is new mail. For some reason, it is currently red, but I am 100% sure that I have no unread mail. Because of this, in the future it will not be as obvious when I have new mail. Is there a way to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10659/mail-glitch/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/700/my-inbox-icon-is-red-even-when-my-inbox-is-empty).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0